# Reverse engineering unknown mpeg4

Tags: video, mpeg-4

I have general programming related question. I have a video in unknown mpeg4 format and I want to write a c program to decode it into a known mpeg4 format. I know nothing about my input mpeg4 format. Any thoughts from where I should begin ?

Regards,
Farrukh Arshad

Comment: Did you study the mpeg4 file structure? There you should find a way to decode the video. This [link](http://mpeg.chiariglione.org/standards/mpeg-4/mpeg-4.htm) seems to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

FFMpeg is an awesome library that allows you to encode/decode using a LOT of codecs. It's also pretty decent at finding the format of a video.

I've used it before to normalize videos into a single format. This was done using shell scripts which were called inside the program, as using the FFMpeg API was something that I didn't have time for at the time; I just wrote a wrapper around the binary executable, which worked fine for my purposes.

The API itself doesn't have the best documentation, but there are example apps, and the default ffmpeg program is also open source, so you can check that out for an example.

Hope this helps.

http://ffmpeg.org/